# Calculate the shops with sales that are above average sales in a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to find the shops that their sales of products are above average sales for a specific period. Here's what I have done until now

```
SELECT S.NAME, SUM([QTY] * [PRICE]) AS SALES, AVG(SALES) AS AVGSALES
FROM Invoice  INNER JOIN InvDetails ON Invoice.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
INNER JOIN Product ON InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID=Product.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN Shop  ON Shop.Shop_ID=Invoice.Shop_ID
WHERE  SALES>AVGSALES  AND DATEOFInv BETWEEN '2010-01-01 08:56:01.490' AND '2010-01-06 06:51:31.867'
GROUP BY S.NAME 
ORDER BY SALES DESC
```

and here is the **error** I get

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'SALES'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'AVGSALES'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'SALES'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try creating an outer block:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT           
        S.NAME, 
        SUM([QTY] * [PRICE]) AS SALES, 
        AVG([QTY] * [PRICE]) AS AVGSALES
    FROM              
        Invoice  INNER JOIN InvDetails ON 
        Invoice.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
        INNER JOIN Product ON InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID=Product.PRODUCT_ID
        INNER JOIN Shop  ON Shop.Shop_ID=Invoice.Shop_ID
    WHERE
        DATEOFInv BETWEEN '2010-01-01 08:56:01.490' AND '2010-01-06 06:51:31.867'
    GROUP BY     S.NAME
)x
    WHERE  
    SALES>AVGSALES
ORDER BY     SALES DESC
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid column name 'SALES'.